# Дуплексный udp коммуникатор. Как дождаться ответа с другой стороны?

Tags: c#, wcf, udp

Пытаюсь удаленно запускать методы между клиентом/сервером.
Вполне успешно.
Проблема возникла когда я захотел дожидаться выполнения удаленно запущенного метода из точки вызова. К тому же я хочу получать результат работы этого метода.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это лучше реализовать?

Обе стороны используют мой Sender, Reciver, и Router. Обмен происходит с помощью Package.

```
    [Serializable]
public class Package
{
    public Guid Sender_Guid { get; set; }
    public IPEndPoint Sender_Endpoint { get; set; }
    public string Target_Controller { get; set; }
    public string Target_Method { get; set; }
    public object[] Params { get; set; }
    public object Response { get; set; }

    public Package() { }
    public Package(object response)
    {
        Response = response;
    }
    public Package(string targetController, string targetMethod, params object[] paramss)
    {
        Target_Controller = targetController;
        Target_Method = targetMethod;
        Params = paramss;
    }
    public Package(string targetController, string targetMethod,
        Guid senderGuid, IPEndPoint senderEndpoint, params object[] paramss)
    {
        Target_Controller = targetController;
        Target_Method = targetMethod;
        Sender_Guid = senderGuid;
        Sender_Endpoint = senderEndpoint;
        Params = paramss;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------
public class Reciver
{
    private Router router;
    //private MessageQueue messageQueue;
    private bool Active;
    private UdpClient receiver;
    private IPEndPoint remoteIp = null;

    public Reciver(short localPort, Router router)
    {
        this.router = router;
        receiver = new UdpClient(localPort);
    }
    private void Recive()
    {
        while (Active)
        {
            byte[] data = receiver.Receive(ref remoteIp);
            Package package = Serializer.Deserialize(data);
            // messageQueue.Enqueue(packge);
            router.Route(package);
        }
    }
    public void StartRecive()
    {
        Active = true;
        new Thread(Recive).Start();
    }
    public void StropRecive()
    {
        Active = false;
        receiver.Close();
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------
public class Sender
{
    private UdpClient sender;

    public Sender()
    {
        sender = new UdpClient();
    }
    public object RomoteCallback(Package package, IPEndPoint Target, bool Return = false)
    {
        byte[] data = Serializer.Serialize(package);
        sender.Send(data, data.Length, Target);
        //тут нужно дождатся ответа и вернуть результат в точку вызова
        return 1;
    }
    public void Response(Package package, IPEndPoint target)
    {
        byte[] data = Serializer.Serialize(package);
        sender.Send(data, data.Length, target);
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------
public class Router
{
    private Dictionary<string, IController> Controllers;
    private Sender sender;

    public Router(Dictionary<string, IController> controllers, Sender sender)
    {
        Controllers = controllers;
        this.sender = sender;
    }
    public void Route(Package package)
    {
        if(package.Response != null)
        {
            //тут нужно отдать результат в ту точку где он ожидается
            return;
        }
        var senderEndpoint = package.Sender_Endpoint;
        var controller = Controllers[package.Target_Controller];
        var method = controller.GetType().GetMethod(package.Target_Method);
        var paramss = package.Params;

        //вызов запрашуемого метода
        var result = method.Invoke(controller, paramss.ToArray());

        //если метод возвращает значение, оправляем результат обратно 
        if (result != null)
        {
            package = new Package(result);
            sender.Response(package, senderEndpoint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: И да, я в курсе что изобретаю велосипед... Все равно прошу подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Вы изобретаете протокол TCP.

UDP - односторонний протокол. Нет уведомлений о доставке пакета, нет вообще никакой обратной связи, как и гарантий доставки пакета на удаленный хост.

Если очень нужно сделать все своими руками - посмотрите описание обмена пакетами в протоколе TCP и реализуйте его самостоятельно. Читать можно [тут(RFC793)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), [тут(RFC793 - перевод)](http://rfc.com.ru/rfc793.htm), и [тут(подробная схема состояний)](http://www.medianet.kent.edu/techreports/TR2005-07-22-tcp-EFSM.pdf), и не только.

Но для начала вам на обоих связанных машинах нужно слушать входящие UDP-пакеты на заданном порту и, как минимум, отвечать на них встречным пакетом с подтверждением получения, вручную разумеется, автоматики там не предусмотрено. Слушать порт нужно постоянно, а значит придется запустить слушателя в отдельном потоке, чтобы не мешал основному приложению, или ждать ответа явно, там, где вы ожидаете его получить. Так как нет гарантий получить ответ - понадобятся таймауты и счетчики для повторных отправок пакета или признания соединения разорванным и т.д. и т.п.

После этого можно начать усложнять схему взаимодействия... Или начать использовать TCP.

Comment: Или посмотреть NFS по UDP...

Comment: @avp как вариант, вариантов вообще много. и TCP не самый лучший из них, но самый известный =)

Comment: TCP, наверное, самый сложный (а главное, меняющий концепцию передачи блоков данных на концепцию потока байт) из них.

Comment: @avp ну не обязательно делать полную реализацию, можно же просто позаимствовать идею в общих чертах, например принцип 3-х рукопожатий при установке соединения.

Comment: На самом деле пакеты теряются редко. Поэтому для синхронного протокола запрос-ответ достаточно таймаута и повторного запроса.

Comment: @avp ага, особенно в мобильном трафике... нам из-за этого пришлось поверх TCP еще один слой надстраивать, для гарантированной доставки и отсутствия повторов.

Comment: @avp впрочем, отсутстве повторов - это уже из другой оперы

Comment: Речь идет не о протоколе общения, я могу заменить на tcp без проблем. Может я не коректно описал проблему, я хочу сделать следуйщие: отправить сообщение, например с сервера на клиент, в котором содерджится информация 1. Имя контроллера(класса); 2. Имя метода; 3. Параметры метода. Клиент получает сообщение и вызывает у себя, через invok, указанный метод,  указанного класса. Если этот метод возвращает значение, оно отправляется обратно на сервер. Сервер в свою очередь должен дождатся этого ответа в том месте где я делал отправку сообщения клиенту.

Comment: @PavelRembrant то что вы описываете и называется протокол, т.е. набор правил обмена информацией. И не важно, передаете вы поток байт или вызываете методы удаленного хоста и ждете результат. В любом случае, при использовании UDP, необходимо вручную дожидаться ответа удаленного хоста, равно как и удаленный хост должен вручную дождаться выполнения метода сообщить о результате.

Comment: В том и был вопрос как релизовать это ваше "вручную дождаться ". В код загляньте.

Comment: @PavelRembrant у вас же уже все есть для этого. После вызова метода через Sender, активируете Receiver и ждете. На другой стороне на каждый входящий пакет, отправляете встречный, либо сразу, если метод не возвращает результатов, либо после выполнения метода.

Comment: На ресивер будут приходить сообщения постоянно от разных клиентов, он всегда активен. Как мне уведомить то место где была отправка RomoteCallback о том что ресивер получил ответ и передать туда результат? Методы же разные и выполнятся будут с разной скоростью.

Comment: @PavelRembrant Receiver должен быть и на клиенте и на сервере. Если клиентов много - запоминайте какой клиент что спрашивал, например по его IP. Ладно, уточняйте текст вопроса, ночером постараюсь описать возможный сценарий. Посмотрите еще на реализацию TCP биндинга в WCF . Там уже есть все что вам нужно.

Comment: @rdorn `поверх TCP еще один слой надстраивать, для гарантированной доставки и отсутствия повторов` -- тогда  вам  попался странный (мягко говоря) TCP.